# Order preserving function

Tags: general-topology

I need an  example of order preserving function but not continuous in infinite spaces is there simple example ?

Comment: Do you want your domain and range to have the _order topology_?

Answer (score 2):

Example: identity: $({\Bbb Z},{\rm indiscrete})\longrightarrow({\Bbb Z},{\rm discrete})$.

Comment: smart (Z,<) Z with magnitude thank you.......